# Unable to pass bundle string

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to get username and pass username to the next activity as shown below but I'm unable to get that in my next activity.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.

    /*Toast.makeText(GoogleLogin.this, 
            currentUser.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


    Intent i = new Intent(GoogleLogin.this,MainActivity.class);

    //Create the bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
    bundle.putString("Google", "Logged in using Google Account");
    bundle.putString("GoogleUsername", currentUser.getDisplayName());
    //Add the bundle to the intent
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);


    // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
}
```

In my Next Activity I'm trying to get as shown:

```
    // 1. get passed intent 
    Intent googleintent = getIntent();

    // 2. get message value from intent
    String UserName = googleintent.getStringExtra("GoogleUsername");

    // 3. get bundle from intent
    Bundle googlebundle = googleintent.getExtras();

    // 4. get status value from bundle
    String googlestatus = googlebundle.getString("Google");


    if (googlestatus.equals("Logged in using Google Account")){ 

    // 5. show message on textView 
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + UserName);
    }
```

I'm not getting username on next activity and the app crashes without any error..But when I'm trying to use toast it shows me the username.

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong?

Comment: As far as my understanding is concerened you want to go to next activity with some data right?

Comment: Yes Exactly that's what I would like to do.

Comment: Try using `intent.PutExtra("GoogleUsername", currentUser.getDisplayName());`

Answer (score 1):

in First Activity

```
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    next_activity.class);
            nextScreen.putExtra("value", "some value");
            startActivity(nextScreen);
```

In Second activity

```
     Intent x = getIntent();                
    String value = x.getStringExtra("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
String UserName = googleintent.getStringExtra("GoogleUsername");
```

It should be `userName` instead. Also, don't forget to correct this line as well:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + UserName);
```

Again, userName needs to start with a lowercase. Capitalized words are reserved for classes/types, not instances.

Also, if your code still doesn't work, try reversing the following two lines.

```
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Instead write (again, only do this if your code doesn't work after my initial correction)

```
startActivity(i);    
i.putExtras(bundle);
```